# How do I use a variable to get CSS info on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, variables

What I have is the following code to create a div.

```
function makeLinkdiv () {
  gCurrentBlock = $gBlockDivName + $gBlockPointer;
  var idPointer = gCurrentBlock;
  var linksBlock = $('<div id ="' + gCurrentBlock + '" class="LinksBlock EditBlock"></div>').appendTo("#canvas");
  linksBlock.draggable({containment: "#canvas", scroll: false, grid: [10, 10]}, {cursor: "move", cursorAt: {top: 125, left: 50}});
  linksBlock.append('<div class="article_title EditBlock fontCenter fontBold font24">Article Title</div>');
  //
  // log the div data to the div object
  //
  var x = gCurrentBlock.css('left');
  var y = gCurrentBlock.css('top');
  alert ('top is - ' + y + ' left is - ' + x);
  divData.items.push({ID: $gBlockPointer, Block: gCurrentBlock, posTop : "450", posLeft : "540" });
  //
  // increment the block pointer
  //
  $gBlockPointer = $gBlockPointer + 1;
  //
}
```

What happens is that I do not get the CSS properties for top and left. Actually, nothing happens. I know that there must be something wrong in how I am using the variable `gCurrentBlock`, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What does you code do? What outer scope variables does that function use (and what do those variables represent)?

Comment: I use it to create new divs for newspaper style layouts.  The variable are pointers and div id's

Comment: You are using `gCurrentBlock` as a string variable, a string doesn't have `css` method.

Comment: So what to I need to do to cast it as a div id?

Comment: @Chris You can select the element after appending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what your code is trying to accomplish... but you need to check out jQuery's `position` and `offset` methods, which will give you coordinates for your element.

I would expect your code to look more like this:

```
...
var position = $('#' + gCurrentBlock).position();
var x = position.left;
var y = position.top;
...
```

And if the values are not what you expect, try changing `position` to `offset`.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  Your code works fine except that I am getting coordinates of the document, not the window that my div is in.  I tried both .offset and .position but no difference.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Just found the problem, it had nothing to do with jquery; my container div was not set to position relative. I changed that and all is good.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `.css()` without using it as a jQuery-object.

Try the following instead:

```
var x = document.getElementById(gCurrentBlock).style.left;
var y = document.getElementById(gCurrentBlock).style.top;
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and nothing happened.  There wasn't an alert box popping up at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here gCurrentBlock is a id in which you are directly using jquery method, so it will not work.

Try `x=$('#'+gCurrentBlock).css('left')` //it will return you left position in pixel like 150px
if you want left position in number you can use

```
 x=$('#'+gCurrentBlock).position().left; //will return x as 150
```

same you can do for y.

```
y=$('#'+gCurrentBlock).css('top');
```

or

```
y=$('#'+gCurrentBlock).position().top;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not selecting the selector in a proper way:

```
 var x = gCurrentBlock.css('left');
 var y = gCurrentBlock.css('top');
```

you have appended it like this:

```
var linksBlock = $('<div id ="' + gCurrentBlock + '" class="LinksBlock EditBlock"></div>').appendTo("#canvas");
//--------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^---this is the id of the div
```

so your code should be :

```
 var x = $('#'+gCurrentBlock).css('left');
 var y = $('#'+gCurrentBlock).css('top');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `gCurrentBlock` is a variable which contains the id of the div only, Thus

Replace this

```
var x = gCurrentBlock.css('left');
```

With

```
var x = $("#"+gCurrentBlock).css('left');
```

Hope this will help !!